# When not to use SQL Cursors and joins

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

Using MySQL, I have table

### Table 1

```
Id  D
--------
A   100
A   125
A   50
B   50
B   25
C   5
C   50
C   50
```

I need new table: which sum id's where = ID's

### table New

```
Id  D 
--------
A   275
B   75
C   105
```

How could I do this using cursor with ID's?
How could using joins and temp table?

Comment: What do you mean by using joins? join to what?

Comment: Under no circumstance would I consider using a cursor for this. Cursors are bad and you should almost never use one. Nor would you need or want to use a temp table.

Comment: @user428 : Why would cursors or temp tables even be a consideration for this?

Comment: @ Campbell thats what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT table2 (ID, D)
SELECT Id, SUM(D) FROM table1 GROUP BY Id
```

Why would you use any of those other methods which are both inefficient and more complicated to write?

Comment: I would use a cursor, and call it "HLGEM_made_this" :p

Comment: @OMG Ponies ,You are evil. I like that in a person.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am not SQL skilled, I know If I asked I would be talked out my ideas, T

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id, SUM(D)
FROM table1
GROUP BY Id
```

Use that select statement to create a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable
SELECT ...
```

Use the same select query with cursors, See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) for examples on cursors .

Comment: Like cursors, I wager the temp table isn't really necessary for the ultimate usage :(

Comment: @omg-ponies I'm with you, plus i don't get the join part of the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I tagged with "aggregate functions" rather than JOINs -- the OP doesn't know what they're asking for.  Which is expected for someone wanting/trying to learn.